# How to make social media like front page in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to make a socialmedia ,i have made profile system where user can upload their respective post but i want to make front page like social media (if any of my followings have uploaded any post i want to see it on my front page ).I have my follower and followngs system.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pic')
    followers=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='followers',blank=True)
    following=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='following',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username},{self.photo}'

class Image(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images_created')
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%d/%m/%y/')
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,db_index=True)
    users_like=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='images_like',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.image},{self.description}'
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    context={}
    return render(request,'socialapp/dashboard.html',context)

def UserRegistration(request):
    form=UserRegistrationForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user=form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            #return HttpResponse(f'Welcome {new_user.first_name} \n Accounted created successfully')
            #return redirect('/register_done/')
            return render(request,'registration/register_done.html',{'new_user': new_user})

            
    else:
        form=UserRegistrationForm()
    context={'form':form,}
    return render(request,'registration/UserRegistration.html',context)


def user_profile(request,username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
    follower_count=profile.followers.count()
    following_count=profile.following.count()
    #photos uploaded 
    user=get_object_or_404(User,username=username)
    img=user.images_created.all()
    

    context={'profile':profile,'user':user,'img':img,'follower_count':follower_count,'following_count':following_count}
    return render(request,'socialapp/user_profile.html',context)


@login_required
def editprofile(request):
    user_form=UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form=ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    if request.method=='POST':
       user_form=UserEditForm(data=request.POST,instance=request.user)
       profile_form=ProfileEditForm(data=request.POST,instance=request.user.profile,files=request.FILES)
       if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid() :
         user_form.save()
         profile_form.save()
         #return HttpResponse('profile saved')
         messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully') 
       else:
         messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
    context={'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form}
    return render(request,'socialapp/editprofile.html',context)

@login_required
def imageview(request):
    form=ImageForm()
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ImageForm(request.POST,files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #cd=form.cleaned_data
            new_form=form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user=request.user
            new_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('form submitted successfully')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('invalid form')
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'socialapp/image.html',context)

    
def search(request):
    search=request.GET['username']
    profiles=Profile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=search)
    #profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=user_id)
    #follower_count=profile.followers.count()
    #following_count=profile.following.count()
    context={'profiles':profiles,}
    return render(request,'socialapp/search.html',context)

def follow(request,id,username):
    profile=Profile.objects.get(id=id)    
    profile.followers.add(request.user)    #adding followers to request.user
    login_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    login_profile.following.add(profile.user)           #adding following to searched profile
    #return redirect(f'/search/?username={username}')
    return redirect(f'/profile/{username}')
    
def unfollow(request,id,username):
    profile=Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    profile.followers.remove(request.user)
    login_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    login_profile.following.remove(profile.user)
    return redirect(f'/profile/{username}')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('login/',views.user_login,name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('dashboard/',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
    path('password_change/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_change.html'),name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/change_password_done.html'),name='password_change_done'),
    path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset.html'),name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/reset_password_done.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/reset_password_confirm.html'),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/reset_password_complete.html'),name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('create_account/',views.UserRegistration,name='create_account'),
    path('register_done/',views.registerdone,name="register_done"),
    path('profile/<str:username>/',views.user_profile,name='profile'),
    path('edit/',views.editprofile,name='edit'),
    path('images/',views.imageview,name='images'),
    path('search/',views.search,name='search'),
    path('follow/<str:id>/<str:username>/',views.follow,name='follow'),
    path('unfollow/<str:id>/<str:username>/',views.unfollow,name='unfollow'),

    ]
```

dashboard.html

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'socialapp/dashboard.css' %}">
<!--<h1>Welcome to Dashboard</h1>-->
<div class="nav">
    <div class="navbar">
        <h1 id="logo">SocialNetwork</h1>
        <!--adding search bar -->
        <form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search" name="username"/>
            <!--<input type="text" placeholder="search" >-->
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>
        <!-- <a href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}" >Profile</a> -->
        <img  class="profile-photo" src="{{user.profile.photo.url}}" height="50px" width="50px">
        <a id="username" href="{% url 'profile' request.user.username %}"><h3 id="username">{{request.user.username}}</h3></a>
        <!--<P id="username">{{request.user.username}}</P>-->
        <a id="username" href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
    </div>
</div><hr color="black">
user_id={{user.pk}},{{user.id}}
profile_id={{user.profile.pk}}<hr>

<a href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change your password</a>
<a href="{% url 'edit' %}">Edit Profile</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please add your `front page` html code

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a view homePage , render out a template , and from the view , give out the posts made by your followers , and show them via for loop or use pagination for that if there are lots of posts .

A simple code bit :

views.py

```
def homePage(request):
    user = request.user
    following_user = user.following.all()
    followed_by_user = user.followers.all()
    the_posts = []
    the_posts+=list(following_user.post_set.all()))
    the_posts+= list(followed_by_user.post_set.all()))
    context = {"posts" : the_posts}
    return render(request, "app/homePage.html" , context = context)
```

Just go to your homePage.html

```
<html>
<body>
{% for post in posts %}
{{post.username}}
{{post.image}}
...
<!-- What ever fields you want -->
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

I think this the thing you want . Hope it solves your problem.